# Can we delete instance user-data from EC2 instance's meta-data in Cloudformation

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We can get the userdata by this command:

http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data

But is there a way to delete this from instance itself?

I know we can delete userdata by stopping it, but rather than doing that, can we delete it from within the instance itself?

Answer (score 3):

Call the [`modify-instance-attribute`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html) command from the AWS CLI.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <your-instance-id> --user-data ":"
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, but I am looking for this option within Cloudformation after instance is stopped

Comment: @davidbob - You asked a question that was answered corrrectly. Then you changed the question. Instead, close this question and create a new question. It is not a supported practice on SO to create "running" questions. If this was allowed, some questions would never be answered and would be useless for the future.

Comment: @davidbob What you are trying to do will require using the CLI, API, or console. Cloudformation is not a scripting language.